# Drastic difference in accuracy for varying batch sizes?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

When training my CNN image classifier using PyTorch I noticed a ~20+% difference in accuracy when using a batch size of 4 vs 32. What might be causing such drastic differences?

**batch_size 4**

```
100%|██████████| 10/10 [02:50<00:00, 17.04s/it, TestAcc=71%, TrainAcc=74%, loss=0.328]
```

**batch_size 32**

```
100%|██████████| 10/10 [02:38<00:00, 15.85s/it, TestAcc=53%, TrainAcc=57%, loss=0.208]
```

Model:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
    self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, 120)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
    self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, num_classes)

def forward(self, x):
    x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
    x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
    x = torch.flatten(x, 1)  # flatten all dimensions except batch
    x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
    x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
    x = self.fc3(x)
    return x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to adjust your learning rate too.
With a larger batch size you should also use a larger learning rate.
[This](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/learning-rate-batch-size) article has additional explanations for the relation of learning rate and batch size.

Comment: Increasing the batch size to 32 and learning rate from 0.0001 to 0.001 solved this issue and resulted in much better accuracies. Thank you.

Comment: I'll just add that training is a stochastic (random) process, so it is possible to get very different results from training run to training run (even with identical parameters).  So unless you do your experiment (training) multiple times (with the same parameters) it is really hard to determine if the different batch size is really the source of the differing outcomes.  That being said, pretty much every knob you can turn (any parameter you can vary) may have an impact on the result... and, what that impact is will vary from problem to problem that you encounter.